# delete of entities in domain driven design

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I started to explore the concepts of domain driven design recently. Most examples and explainations I find do assume there is a kind of ORM tool being used to persist the entities in the repository.

At this moment, I am leaning towards the use of Entity Framework as the ORM tool, however some issues come to my mind which might als be applicable with other tools. For example, assume there is a root aggregate Order with multiple OrderLine entities as child:

- Order has a readonly collection property exposing the OrderLines
- add and delete of orderlines is implemented by specific methods on the order
- when adding or deleting orderlines, the total price of the order needs to be changed accordingly

  1. What is the preferred way to detect additions of new OrderLines when saving the Order? In the repository I could check for the value of the id to detect if an line needs to be added or updated. Is this the proper way to do this?
  2. How does the order repository detect deletions of lines?
  3. How do you restore an entity from the database when some properties are only private settable?

These examples are easy to implement when exposing a public modifyable collection on the root aggregate, but that makes it possible to modify the collection without using the dedicated methods. Same is true for the restoration with private properties: make them public settable.

And what if I do not want to use an ORM tool, but direct SQL queries, how would the issues be addressed best in that case? Ideally, the domain model would not require modifications in that case, because the way how the changes are persisted is an implementation detail of the repository, so this coult be either EF, NHibernate or plain old SQL.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. SO is for answers to specific technical questions. This question will just lead to debate.

Comment: Most ORMs are capable of detecting these changes automatically through a Unit of Work. You would basically have to implement a UoW yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Domain Driven Design is about modeling a problem in a way that the coders and project managers and business owners all can understand... http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html

You will find the problem owners do not use the word DELETE from cart, they would use the word REMOVE item from cart or ADD item to cart.

The detection and calculation of total variables is managed by an aggregate root entity (the cart) of which there are child entities (products). http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

For a DDD project don't start tackling the problem with worrying about how to store the data, start by worrying about how the code (entities) model the problem being solved.

Since people speak in terms of events when explaining a problem, "user added to the item to the cart, so the total should update", it often makes sense to model the problem as things that react and apply updates when events happen.

This is where event sourcing really shines as there is no longer a mismatch between the entity code and storage that can sometimes come from using an ORM tool as everything (the problem and the code) is explained in its native language of events.

By storing each event, you can replay all the events and rebuild the current state incrementally.

Each event stored is immutable, once created it cannot change, this would be done via parameters in the constructor setting read only fields:

```
// in UserAddedItemToCart.cs
public class UserAddedItemToCart
{
    public UserAddedItemToCart(int productId)
    {
        this.ProductId = productId;
    }

    public readonly int ProductId;  
}

// in UserRemovedItemFromCart.cs
public class UserRemovedItemFromCart
{
    public UserAddedItemToCart(int productId)
    {
        this.ProductId = productId;
    }

    public readonly int ProductId;
}

// in Cart.cs
public class Cart : AggregateBase
{
    private readonly HashSet<int> Items = new HashSet<int>();

    public void AddItem(int itemId)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new UserAddedItemToCart(itemId));
    }

    public void RemoveItem(int itemId)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new UserRemovedItemFromCart(itemId));
    }

    // wired up via base class
    protected void Apply(UserAddedItemToCart evnt)
    {
        this.Items.Add(evnt.ProductId);
    }

    // wired up via base class
    protected void Apply(UserRemovedItemFromCart evnt)
    {
        this.Items.Remove(evnt.ProductId);
    }

    public int[] ItemsInCart
    {
        get { return this.Items.ToArray(); }
    }
}
```

Some links that I found useful when I had the same question as you and changed from thinking in terms of deleting things and instead considering the events that happen:

https://geteventstore.com/
https://geteventstore.com/blog/20130220/getting-started-part-2-implementing-the-commondomain-repository-interface/
https://github.com/NEventStore/CommonDomain

You can check the AggregateBase to see how it stores the events, and the implementing-the-commondomain-repository-interface link above to see how the two link to rebuild everything without having public setters (you should still model your code so everything is protected by the aggregate root).

Don't get too focused on how the ORM stores your data. If it makes more sense to access via CRUD and control as create, read, update, delete, then just model the problem that way.

DDD with event sourcing can add even more complexity, so use responsibly and only if it will add value to your project in reduced time for adding features later on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into event sourcing as a way to persist data.

> Event sourcing is a way of persisting your application's state by storing the history that determines the current state of your application.

It works very well in conjunction with DDD.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591559.aspx#sec1

In your scenario you describe you would store an something like an OrderLineItemAddedEvent or and OrderLineItemDeletedEvent (each with all the item information usually stored as a JSON blob) and then when you want to reload the aggregate you simply replay all the events in the order they were persisted to return your object to the correct state.